# How to convert string to NSDate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

How can I convert a string like `05/18/2017` this to `NSDate`?

I am trying to convert this string to `NSDate` so that I can extract the day as **18** and month as **05** and year as **2017**. How can I convert this or can extract those values from strings.

```
func toDate(dateString : String, dateFormat : String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")-> NSDate!{
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
  dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
  let convertedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
  return convertedDate
}
```

Now in code below `selectedValue` is `05/18/2017` but `NSDateFromString` always shows nil value:

```
let nsdateFromString = String.toDate(selectedValue)
```

What can I do in this case?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" vs "05/18/2017" How do you think that's supposed to match?

Comment: If you want to extract the components use `NSDateComponents` (and consider to update to Swift 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `dateFormat` value of your function `toDate` not matching the `selectedValue`'s date format, so you need to pass `dateFormat` argument also with your method call with value `MM/dd/yyyy`.

```
let nsdateFromString = String.toDate(dateString: selectedValue, dateFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: @iron Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 4):

```
**in SWIFT 3.0,**


let strDate = "12/21/2017"
let datefrmter = DateFormatter()
datefrmter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
let date = datefrmter.date(from: strDate)
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func convertSToD(date : String)-> Date?{
        if date != "NA"{
        let interval = Double(date)
        let dateFormat = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval!)
        return dateFormat
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
func toDate(dateString : String, dateFormat : String = "MM/dd/yyyy")-> NSDate!{
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
return convertedDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Current date and time

```
let formatter1 = DateFormatter()

        let date1 = Date.init()
        formatter1.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"
        let days = formatter1.string(from: date1 as Date)

        print(days)
```

Comment: Your format is wrong (read the question) and the cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in Swift 3.0 converting string to NSDate with its format
let dateString = self.scoring_date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

self.dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString! as String )!

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: self.dateObj))")

//converting NSDate to String
let today = Date()
today.toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM")
```